# multiple language php & stylesheet

Tags: php, static, stylesheet, multilingual

I have static php file wanna to do a multi lang on it and i success to do it already

by using this tuts
[how-i-created-simple-multi-lingual-static-website-in-php](http://bhargavg.wordpress.com/2011/12/29/how-i-created-simple-multi-lingual-static-website-in-php/)

but i have a small issue when i change between the language i wanna to change the link stylesheet as well cuz some of the lang must use a rtl stylesheet so my Question is

How i change the lang and the stylesheet at the same time ?

Am really need help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Almost you have finished.
In `<head>` just add,

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['lang'] == 'de') {
?>
<link href="css/de.css" rel="stylesheet">
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<link href="css/en.css" rel="stylesheet">
<?php
}
?>
```

**Note:** For multi-language sites, Better have common stylesheet for components like `<select>`,`<input>`,`<a>`,etc. And just have seperate stylesheets for ***font sizes, styles*** or so.